# Find $\arctan x_1 \cdot \arctan x_2$, where $x_1$ and $x_2$ are roots of $x^2 - 2\sqrt{2}x + 1 = 0$.

Tags: trigonometry

I am told that $x_1$ and $x_2$ are the roots of the following equation:

$$ x^2 - 2\sqrt{2}x + 1 = 0 $$

And I have to find the following:

$$\hspace{6cm} \arctan x_1 + \arctan x_2 \hspace{5cm} (1)$$

$$\hspace{6.cm} \arctan x_1 \cdot \arctan x_2 \hspace{5.3cm} (2)$$

Now I know that, in general:

$$\arctan(a) + \arctan(b) = \arctan \bigg ( \dfrac{a + b}{1 - ab} \bigg )$$

So $(1)$ is not that difficult to find, it actually equals $\dfrac{\pi}{2}$. 
The problem is that I don't know how to find $(2)$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With $x_1+x_2=2\sqrt2$ and $x_1x_2=1$,

$$S_+=\arctan x_1 + \arctan x_2 = \arctan \bigg ( \dfrac{x_1 + x_2}{1 - x_1x_2} \bigg )=\arctan (\infty) =\frac\pi2$$

With $x_1-x_2= \sqrt{(x_1+x_2)^2-4x_1x_2}=2$,

$$S_-=\arctan x_1 - \arctan x_2 = \arctan \bigg ( \dfrac{x_1 - x_2}{1 + x_1x_2} \bigg )=\arctan (1)=\frac\pi4$$

Then,
$$\arctan x_1\cdot \arctan x_2 = \frac14(S_++S_-)(S_+-S_-)
=\frac14(S_+^2-S_-^2)=\frac{3\pi^2}{64}$$

Comment: Can you please explain the reasoning behind that last line you wrote? Why is the product of the arctangents equal to $\frac{1}{4}(S_{+}^2 - S_{-}^2)$? Is this a formula? Did you deduce it?

Comment: @user1502 - Note $S_{\pm}^2 = \arctan^2 x_1 \pm 2\arctan x_1 \cdot \arctan x_2+ \arctan^2 x_2$. Therefore,$S_+^2-S_-^2=2\arctan x_1 \cdot \arctan x_2 - (-2\arctan x_1 \cdot \arctan x_2)=4\arctan x_1 \cdot \arctan x_2$

Answer (score 4):

As far as I can tell, there is no clean, generalized way to find $\arctan(x) \cdot \arctan(y)$. However, the roots for this specific equation are $\sqrt{2}-1$ and $\sqrt{2}+1$. $\arctan{\left(\sqrt{2}-1\right)} = \frac{\pi}{8}$ and $\arctan{\left(\sqrt{2}+1\right)} = \frac{3\pi}{8}$. So in this case we can directly calculate the product $\frac{3\pi^2}{64}$.

Comment: But how did you find that $\arctan(\sqrt{2} - 1) = \frac{\pi}{8}$ and that $\arctan(\sqrt{2} + 1) = \frac{3 \pi}{8}$? I see no clear way of finding these two.

Answer (score 2):

With $x=\tan a$, $$\tan^2a-2\sqrt2\tan a+1=0$$ can easily be rewritten as $$\sin 2a=\sin\frac\pi4.$$

Thus the solutions with $a\in(-\frac\pi2,\frac\pi2)$ are

$$2a_1=\frac\pi4\text{ and }2a_2=\frac{3\pi}4,$$

giving
$$a_1a_2=\frac{3\pi^2}{64}.$$

Answer (score 1):

The roots of the equation are $ x_1 = \sqrt{2} + 1$ and $ x_2 =\sqrt{2} - 1 $. So we can explicitly work out $ \arctan(x_1) \, \cdot \, \arctan(x_2) = \frac{\pi}{8} \, \cdot \, \frac{3\pi}{8} = \frac{3\pi^2}{64} $